# Layout with frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, framed

This is my first post! I have been around this Forum for some time, but I never needed to ask a question. Unfortunately I can't find a answer suitable for me Problem this time.

I am trying to re-create in Latex the word template shown below.

[image]

I managed to design the outer Frame and the margins as in the original template, however, I got no clue how to make the Header an Footer table. Especially I want the Latex template to fill out the "Spec No.", "Revision", "Title" and "Date" fields automaticly, i.e. these values need to be changed for every new text written with the template.

Can someone help me? My current code is

```
\documentclass
{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[all]{background}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{layout}

\newcommand{\myborderedpage}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]
            ($ (current page.south west) + (2.2cm,1.2cm) $)
            rectangle
            ($ (current page.north east) + (-1.4cm, -0.9cm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \sffamily
        }

\SetBgContents{\myborderedpage}

\SetBgPosition{current page.north west}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select roation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo

\voffset=0mm
\topmargin = -16.4mm
\headheight=16.4mm
\headsep = 2.6mm
\textheight=240mm
\footskip=22.5mm


\hoffset=-0.5mm
\oddsidemargin=0mm
\textwidth=170mm

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
%\layout

%\begin{titlepage}
%\end{titlepage}

\section{lorem Ipsum}


\end{document}
```

regards
Splam

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263655/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108374/1952

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.